# Modifying the default value of a function argument

Tags: python

I have the following modules:

cat.py:

```
DEFAULT_SOUND='meow'

def make_sound(sound=DEFAULT_SOUND):
    print(sound)
```

animal.py

```
import cat

def sound():
    cat.make_sound()
```

I need to call `animal.sound`, but I'd like the cat to make a different sound. I tried this:

```
import animal

# Change the sound
import cat
cat.DEFAULT_SOUND='nyan'

animal.sound()
```

but it didn't work (the output is `meow`). In retrospect, this is not surprising if the default value was set from the value of DEFAULT_SOUND at the time cat.py was processed by Python.

Is there a way for the cat to make a different sound? Neither `animal.py` nor `cat.py` is editable by me, although I can ask their maintainers to make changes.
`animal.sound` is actually several nested calls, and it's impossible to change all of them to pass a sound through.

Comment: "`animal.sound` is actually several nested calls, and it's impossible to change all of them to pass a sound through." - the handling of this value needs to be redesigned.

Comment: I really hope this is a purely academic question, because thinking about trying to debug a problem in a codebase that does stuff like this is causing me physical pain.

Comment: @SamStafford At least `cat.make_sound` takes a parameter. It could easily have been implemented as `print('meow')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `partial` function from `functools` module.
[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is the documentation.

> Return a new partial object which when called will behave like func
>   called with the positional arguments args and keyword arguments
>   keywords.

```py
from functools import partial

import animal
import cat

cat.make_sound = partial(cat.make_sound, sound='nyan')

animal.sound()
```

```
nyan
```